# Unable to load jupyter notebook

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter-notebook

How to solve this issue of Jupyter extension loaded from C and jupyter application directory is something else.I am unable to use numpy and matplotlib in Jupyter notebook.

[this is what I get in Anaconda Prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ET2gy.png)

[These are the two errors I get 302 and 404 when I host the notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97Gm3.png)

[This is I got when I run a code in notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzxEr.png)

[continued...error I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZ9zJ.png)

Comment: The screenshot shows nothing wrong. It is giving you a (local) URL to open to access the Jupyter notebook. Copy the localhost:8888 URL and open it in your browser.

Comment: may you again check my screenshots again...cuz I am getting errors only when I import some package from the library like numpy and matplotlib..otherwise I can run simple python code.Help will be appreciated

Comment: Well, have you tried the suggested solutions from your own image?

Comment: First step I would try re-install numpy `pip3 install numpy`

Comment: yes..I have tried the suggested solution still unable to use numpy and matplotlib in jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 0):

It usually happens when the application is not able to initiate or determine a default browser. Just copy the entire link `http://localhost:8888/?token=4e558da5a28601f99fbc0f1773a4200c57e89b6d487de19a` and paste it in a web browser similar to how you access any web url. Remember, the token changes every time you initiate the jupyter notebook.

Comment: may you again check my screenshots again...cuz I am getting errors only when I import some package from the library like numpy and matplotlib..otherwise I can run simple python code.Help will be appreciated.

Comment: @VishalSharma, You have multiple questions here. You should ask them separately. Your screenshot of jupyter notebook is not showing the full code and full error message. The code also doesn't have line numbers to associate the error with the code. Could you, please make those changes and post the code and error again.